# Why is my Windsor Container saying it can't resolve this dependency even though it can?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, interceptor

Given the following code:

```
using Castle.DynamicProxy;
using Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;
using Castle.Windsor;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
            container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
            container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                .BasedOn<IAuditInterceptor>()
                .WithServiceDefaultInterfaces()
                .LifestyleTransient());
            container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                .BasedOn(typeof(ICommandHandler<>))
                .WithServiceAllInterfaces()
                .Configure(c => c.Interceptors<IAuditInterceptor>().LifestyleTransient()));

            container.Register(Component.For<ICommandHandlerFactory>().AsFactory());

            var factory = container.Resolve<ICommandHandlerFactory>();

            var handlers = factory.GetHandlersForCommand<DummyCommand>();

            handlers.First().Handle(new DummyCommand());
        }
    }

    public interface IAuditInterceptor : IInterceptor
    {

    }

    public interface ICommand
    {

    }

    public interface ICommandHandler<T> where T : ICommand
    {
        void Handle(T command);
    }

    public interface ICommandHandlerFactory
    {
        ICommandHandler<T>[] GetHandlersForCommand<T>() where T : ICommand;
    }


    public class DummyCommand : ICommand
    {

    }

    public class DummyCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<DummyCommand>
    {

        public void Handle(DummyCommand command)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from command handler");
        }
    }

    public class AuditInterceptor : IAuditInterceptor
    {

        public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Interceptor before");
            invocation.Proceed();
            Console.WriteLine("Interceptor After");
        }
    }
}
```

The code runs and executes as expected, and the interceptor fires and the program completes normally. However, if you do a check for potentially misconfigured components, you get told that

> Some dependencies of this component could not be statically resolved.
>   'ConsoleApplication1.DummyCommandHandler' is waiting for the following
>   dependencies:
>   - Component 'ConsoleApplication1.IAuditInterceptor' (via override) which was not found. Did you forget to register it or misspelled the
>   name? If the component is registered and override is via type make
>   sure it doesn't have non-default name assigned explicitly or override
>   the dependency via name.

What causes this? The code runs and executes without problem. Why does Windsor say it can't find `IAuditInterceptor`?

This goes away if you remove the injection of `IAuditInterceptor` and register the concrete type `AuditInterceptor` by itself, like this:

```
container.Register(Component.For<AuditInterceptor>().LifestyleTransient());
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
            .BasedOn(typeof(ICommandHandler<>))
            .WithServiceAllInterfaces()
            .Configure(c => c.Interceptors<AuditInterceptor>().LifestyleTransient()));
```

Comment: Register the implementation for the interface, too: container.Register(Component.For<IAuditInterceptor>().ImplementedBy<AuditInterceptor>().LifestyleTransient()).

Comment: @KBO doing that defeats the purpose of doing it by convention. I'd like the interceptor injected like a dependency.

Comment: Maybe, the convention 'container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
.Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Interceptor"))  .WithServiceDefaultInterfaces().LifestyleTransient())' works?